# "То же" или "тоже"?

Tags: частица

*То же* касается попыток ввоза и вывоза незадекларированных животных. *То же* раздельно?

Comment: Возможны варианты. Нужен контекст.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае **то же** -- раздельно. Если к **ТО(ЖЕ)** по смыслу можно добавить слово **САМОЕ**, то перед нами местоимение + частица.
Они пишутся раздельно: **ТО ЖЕ**. 
*То же (самое) касается попыток ввоза и вывоза незадекларированных животных.*

Примеры: Я **тоже** интересуюсь биологией (значение присоединения, союз **тоже**).
Я стараюсь делать **то же**, что и другие, но у меня никак не получается (значение указания, местоимение **то** и частица **же**).

http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-194

Answer (score 2):

То же касается попыток ввоза... Здесь "то же" раздельно, его можно заменить союзом "и". Это касается И попыток ввоза...  Контекст не нужен.